# Working with Visual Studio, Trying to add CSS to an individual "table colspan" to customize the pre-built login box

Tags: css

I'm a front-end web developer that is new to working with Visual Stuido, and am having trouble trying to add my css to the pre-built in login box.  I just don't know the proper css code to call on an individual td colspan?

This seems to work:

```
td {
color: Red;
```

}

..but it changes every single td on the page

This doesn't seem to work:

```
td colspan="2" {
color: Red;
```

}

..I don't know what the proper css code is to call on an individual colspan? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

¿It is possible to add a class attribute to the login box td?

If you can, just type:

```
<td class="red" colspan="2">
```

and then in the CSS:

```
td.red {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: No..., thats the issue w/ working with the pre-built in Visual Studio tools..., The only way that I know that its the td colspan="2" is because I'm using FireBug.

Comment: This is the only code that gives me: `<p>
                <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" LoginButtonText="" TitleText="" BorderPadding="0" BorderStyle="None"></asp:Login>
            </p>` ........ and that produces the username and password text, username and password box, and login button... It's all pre-built in. But I did find out that I could use Firebug to help me find the "default" names of id's and classes that it naturally produces... This Visual Studio stuff is a bit different